# i want query should return the all result of employee no matter if the name of employee is in different column

Tags: mysql, exists

I want the result in a such a way that it should return the all employee details if the value which I am going to mention in where clause is in different column.

so for that i have write my query like:-

```
select * 
from claim_master 
where full_name='Trevor DSouza' in (select * from claim_master);
```

i.e I want the query should show the result if `'Trevor DSouza'` name is exist in different column.
but it shows the result as:-

> Error Code: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

please help me to solve my error.please

Comment: I don't see why you think you need the IN clause.  The requirement of "any column" is wrong headed. Maybe you are thinking of an unstructured document and an index solution like SOLR, not a MySQL relational database

Comment: sir, how we can search 'Trevor DSouza' value if it is in other column. i mean it also return the result if 'Trevor DSouza' is in other column. i want to search the table for this value and don't want to mention the column name

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

you have to mention the column name in the query it will not work like the above you have written. You can use the below snippet and try:

```
select 
    * 
    from 
    claim_master 
    where full_name like 'Trevor DSouza' 
    OR last_name like 'Trevor DSouza' 
    OR other_column_name like 'Trevor DSouza';
```

just add the columns name in or conditions.